# On delete set null in hibernate in @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a Department entity which relations are as follows:

1. **Many departments** can be in **one parent department**:

   ```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "ik_parent_department_id")
   private Department parentDepartment;
   ```
2. **One parent department** can have **many departments**:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentDepartment")
   private Set<Department> children = new HashSet<Department>(0);
   ```

And I want to implement the next: When I **delete** a **department**, then the **ik_parent_department_id** parameter of all **children** of this **department** is set to **null**. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have JPA/Hibernate to replicate the "ON DELETE SET NULL" functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944137/have-jpa-hibernate-to-replicate-the-on-delete-set-null-functionality)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to set the children's `ik_parent_department_id` to null explicitly.

```
Department parentDepartment = (Department) session.load(Department.class, id);
session.delete(parentDepartment);
for (Department child : parentDepartment.getChildren()){
    child.setParentDepartment(null);
} 
session.flush();
```

With cascading you would only manage to delete child `Departments`.

Comment: No there is not. It is possible to set up the fk in the db to do this in some databases but the support is limited. E.g. with sql server you run into problems with circle references so implementing the logic into the code looks like proposed. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944137/have-jpa-hibernate-to-replicate-the-on-delete-set-null-functionality

Answer (score 14):

With JPA, in parent `Entity` you might have something like

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
Collection<Child> children;
```

and in order to avoid possible repeating "set null code" & integrity violation exceptions on parent removal implement in parent `Entity` also

```
@PreRemove
private void preRemove() {
   children.forEach( child -> child.setParent(null));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. My question is: Is there a way of doing this only with cascade operations?

Answer (score 6):

Just code it:

```
for (Department child : parent.getChildren()) {
    child.setParentDepartment(null);
}
session.delete(parent);
```