# JPA one-to-many delete and set foreign key to null

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I use `Spring Data JPA` and `MySQL`. I have *one* to *many* relation between `Event` and `Category`. Obviously:

- one `Event` can have only one `Category`
- one `Category` can be assigned many `Event`s.

The problem appears when I try to remove `Category`, if any `Event` hold a *foreign key* of this `Category` then I get an error. I would like to set the *foreign key* in the `Event` table to `null` when a `Category` is deleted.

At the moment I update all `Event`s by setting the *foreign key* explicitly in the code by updating it to `null` before deletion of `Category`. Is there any way of doing it in use of annotations?

This is the `Category` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", 
               targetEntity=Event.class, 
               fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
               cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,  
                         CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    public Set<Event> getEvents_category() {
       return events_category;
    }

}
```

This is the `Event` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, 
                        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="events_dancestyle")
    public DanceStyle getDanceStyle() {
       return danceStyle;
    }

}
```

I've seen that the topic was discussed many times but I haven't seen any solution to that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to do this using JPA/Hibernate annotations. See these related questions:

[Have JPA/Hibernate to replicate the "ON DELETE SET NULL" functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944137/have-jpa-hibernate-to-replicate-the-on-delete-set-null-functionality)

[On delete set null in hibernate in @OneToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243400/on-delete-set-null-in-hibernate-in-onetomany)

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your answer. Your answer just confirmed that I was correct. I used exactly the same approach as in the links you gave.

Answer (score 1):

1- the best way is to write cascade = CascadeType.DETACH

2- but you should write above Class Event

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE event SET deleted=true WHERE id=?")
```

3- inside the Event Class

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean deleted;
```

4- Then when you delete category
if CascadeType.ALl the "deleted" attribute of Event entity will affected by 1 (true).
if CascadeType.DETACH the "deleted" attribute of Event entity will not affected and still 0 (false).