# One to One Mapping Deletion Scenario

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, rdbms

```
Class Employee{
//one to one
Department dep;
}

Class Department{
String name

}
```

My question is how do I handle a scenario where I have to delete a department but not the employee  row
Do I need to manually delete a reference of a department from an employee and then delete the dep or can I use a cascade feature but in that case do not want to delete the parent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you'd want Many-To-One from Employee to Department. If you'd also add One-To-Many from Department to Employee, you could use the @PreRemove feature as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435269/561543)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I thought of using one to many but wanted to explore one to one too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use a `cascading delete` in the database you are using.  The `cascading delete` generally allows at least two options:

- `on delete cascade` which deletes the rows in the referencing table (what you do **not** want).
- `on delete set null` which sets the reference to `NULL`.

Your particular database may offer other options as well.  You should check the documentation.